# Use APEX application items within SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have two APEX application items called `AI_TABLE` and `AI_ERROR` and I need to use them in an SQL query. Not sure how to use them and can't find a tutorial this even though it seems like quite a simple thing...

```
SELECT *
FROM :AI_TABLE a
WHERE a.ERROR_TEXT = :AI_ERROR
```

I'd ideally want this to show in the interactive report format. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot bind the table name `:AI_TABLE` at run time in native SQL, you will need to use dynamic PL/SQL; or in Apex create a report region of the type `SQL Query (PL/SQL function body returning SQL query)`:

```
RETURN 'SELECT * FROM '|| :AI_TABLE || ' a WHERE a.ERROR_TEXT = ' || :AI_ERROR;
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't see where to choose that type of report though.

Comment: Hmm, is there no way to have this as an interactive report?

Comment: I don't believe that is an option for an interactive report. However, you could populate an [Apex Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17556_01/doc/apirefs.40/e15519/apex_collection.htm) via a procedure using dynamic PL/SQL on page load, and then reference the collection in the interactive report.